# How to get URL in outSequence?

Tags: clone, response, wso2

I use clone to send a request to different servers, and use aggregate in `outSequence`. It can receive all response. Some may success, and some may response error. But I don't know which server response error. I think I need get `URL` for any response messages.

Anyone can help me?

**My service config code is here:**

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="CloneTest" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <clone id="12345">
            <target>
               <endpoint>
                  <address uri="http://172.21.11.21:28888/usm/services/receiveMsg" format="pox" />
               </endpoint>
            </target>
            <target>
               <endpoint>
                  <address uri="http://172.21.11.22:28888/usm/services/receiveMsg" format="pox" />
               </endpoint>
            </target>
         </clone>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
            <aggregate>
                <completeCondition>
                    <messageCount min="10" max="10"/>
                </completeCondition>
                <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the Remote address/ host using following properties. Use to filter based on those values.

```
   <property name="Remote address --> " expression="get-property('axis2','REMOTE_ADDR')"/>
   <property name=" Remote host ---->" expression="get-property('axis2','REMOTE_HOST')"
```